# Bash ternary operation gives same output on either Boolean condition

Tags: bash, ternary

So in my bash script, I output status report to terminal as well as write it to the log file. I wanted to use a bash ternary operator that will output to terminal as well as write a log file if variable `LOG_TO_TERMINAL` is true, and if that is set to false, just write to a log file without outputting status to the terminal.

My sample code looks like this:

```
[[ $LOG_TO_TERMINAL ]] && echo "error message" >> $LOG_FILE || echo "error message" | tee -a $LOG_FILE
```

which just logs the file instead of echoing to the terminal no matter whether I set `LOG_TO_TERMINAL` to `true` or `false`.

To isolate the problem, I tried simplifying the code to:

```
[[ $LOG_TO_TERMINAL ]] && echo "log to terminal" || echo "don't log to terminal"
```

But this code snippet also echoes "log to terminal" no matter what its value is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test `[[ $LOG_TO_TERMINAL ]]` tests whether `LOG_TO_TERMINAL` has a value or not. Nothing else. The shell doesn't treat `false` (or `0` or `null` etc.) as special false-y values.

If you want some other test you need to test specifically for that.

```
[[ $LOG_TO_TERMINAL = true ]]
```

or

```
[[ $LOG_TO_TERMINAL != false ]]
```

or

```
[[ $LOG_TO_TERMINAL = 1 ]]
```

etc.

If you were expecting to use the return code from the `true` and/or `false` *commands* then you need `$LOG_TO_TERMINAL && Y || Z` or similar to run the command stored in the variable (though I wouldn't recommend this version of this test).

Also note that `X && Y || Z` is **not** a ternary operation in the shell. See the Shellcheck wiki for warning [SC2015](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2015) for more about this.

Comment: Thank you. So it looks like `A && B || C` should be avoided. Then is "if then else" the best way for my purpose? Also, I have another line `[[ -f $FILE ]] || {echo "$FILE not found" | tee -a $LOG_FILE; exit}`. This code should be fine, right?

Comment: You can use `A && B || C` if you understand its actual behavior. In your case, for example, it is perfectly fine since `echo` should never be able to fail but you couldn't use it as `can_fail && might_fail || something_else`. Yes, that second example is fine as that's just an `A || B` case (where `B` is a list of commands).

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
[[ $LOG_TO_TERMINAL = 1 ]] && echo "log to terminal" || echo "don't log to terminal"
```